# What is the difference between a charge card and a credit card?

Tags: credit-card, expenses

There used to be a type of card that was offered called a "charge" card, how is that different from a credit card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot carry a balance on a charge card; the total balance is due as the payment each period.

I guess some government use charge cards.  There is no interest to be paid on them, so it is cheaper, but the credit companies still make some money on transaction fees.

- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge%5Fcard)
- http://www.thesimpledollar.com/2009/04/13/personal-finance-101-charge-cards-versus-debit-cards-versus-credit-cards-pros-and-cons/
- http://www.frbsf.org/publications/consumer/cards.html

Answer (score 3):

There's also a "debit" card in some countries which acts the same as a credit / charge card, except each transaction is subtracted from the account balance immediately, and the account cannot be in debit.

Comment: That depends on the account type: if the account to which the debit card is attached has an overdraft facility, then it can certainly be in debit (to the amount of the overdraft, but no more).